# Unable to connect to network share from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, samba, network-shares

I've got a samba server where I'm entitled to access to 2 different shares, with the same login.

I can't access from my PC under Windows 7 Pro to the first share, \\192.168.1.3\share1, and browse all sub directories.

But I am rejected when trying to access to the second share, \\192.168.1.3\share2 !!!

From a Linux PC, I've tested my credentials with smbclient, and I can well connect to share 2 and access all its content.

What can be wrong with my PC?

Thanks in advances for any tips,
Raoul

Comment: I can't see that my problem is not really popular. Maybe because you lack of details? What can of logs or infos can I gave you to go further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hust to let you know, that now, the problem is solved on my PC.

I think this procedure http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934160 makes it work.

Best regards,
Raoul

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar problem.  In my case I have a Windows 7 machine ( host ) with an Ubuntu VirtualBox ( guest ).

Guest virtual machine is running Samba well configured and fine tuned, tested.  But wen I try to access from Windows7 host machine I got an error like *The Account Is Not Authorized to Login from This Station*

After tried some fixes, the one that worked was this:

Open RegEdit and change 3 flags:

```
HKLM\System\Current control set\Control\LSA
LMCompatibilityLevel **(set to 0x1)**


HKLM\System\Current control set\Services\LanManWorkstation\Parameters\
```

`RequireSecuritySignature` **(set to 0x0)**

`EnableSecuritySignature` **(set to 0x0)**

I hope it will be useful for anybody.

I've read this fix here (Spanish): 
https://docsharing.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/windows-vista-7-y-servidor-samba/